# How to accomplish onHover event without a second image

Tags: html, css

I was visiting this site: **http://vsearch.nlm.nih.gov/vivisimo/cgi-bin/query-meta?v:project=medlineplus&query=**

I came across the "GO" button and I am baffled as to how the color is changing to GREEN from PURPLE. I looked in the CSS and also even downloaded the image but cannot figure it out.

Can someone tell me how it's possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *is* using a separate image.

Normal state: http://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/images/search_go.png

Hover state: http://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/images/search_go_rollover.png

Comment: Note that the actual src attribute of the <input> tag is changing, which indicates that it's being accomplished via JavaScript, not CSS.

Comment: Completely missed it! How were you able to find the hover state image?

Comment: In Google Chrome, I just right-clicked on the button and selected "Inspect Element". Then, I looked at the tag while mousing on and off the button.

(Unlike "View Source" - which simply shows the original state of the HTML as it was downloaded from the server - "Inspect Element" shows you the *live* state of the DOM, and therefore reflects any modifications that have been made to the page via JavaScript.)

Answer (score 1):

It is the file: http://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/jslib/control27.js

and this is the code:

```
_o = jQuery("#frmSearchBottom").find(":input[type='image']");
  _o.blur(function(evt) {
  this.src = pagepath+"/images/search_go"+_ext;
  });
  _o.mouseover(function(evt) {
  this.src = pagepath+"/images/search_go_rollover"+_ext;
  });
  _o.mouseout(function(evt) {
      this.src = pagepath+"/images/search_go"+_ext;
  });
  _o.focus(function(evt) {
      this.src = pagepath+"/images/search_go_rollover"+_ext;
  });
```